# I want child route to be dynamic Like i'm clicking on categories and generating url in component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

**routing.module.ts:**
 I want child route to be dynamic Like I'm clicking on categories and generating url in component. I want snapshot of url to be used as path in `routing.ts`. How could I do that?

```
Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: SettingsComponent,
        children: [
        {
            path: 'settingId', component: SettingsComponent
        }
    }
]
```

**component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.settingId = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
});
```

Comment: path: any  <!--     may be a string   --!>

Comment: `path: "setting:id"` would be correct. So you call "setting:notification" and then you can access `id` (in this case "notification") like that `this.route.params.subscribe(params => {});`

Answer (score 0):

first import routes to component where you want to change path. Then you can access routes in your component and change path value.

app.routing.ts:

```
export let routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',

        component: exampleComponent,

        children: [

            {

                path: '',

                component: SettingsComponent
            }
      }
]
```

exampleComponent.ts :

```
// importing routes
import { routes } from '../app.routing';

// i'm changing it in ngOnInit for example.
ngOnInit() {
 this.settingId = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
 routes[0].children[0].path = this.settingId;

}
```